# When will Salesforce1 be available for Windows 8

Tags: salesforce1-app, windows8

I have a number of Windows 8 only device users and I would like to know when the Salesforce1 will be available as an app for this O/S.

Comment: It's available in the browser today.  Why the need for an app?

Comment: @Jagular I agree with this. Windows 8 tablets and other touch screens would benefit. Sync your session across multiple devices, access to the local device calendar via Today, and less bandwidth usage by leveraging a native client, plus eventually offline support.

Comment: That might be a feature request. Have you looked in success.salesforce.com to see?

Comment: @Jagular how about offline access to start with...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A preview is planned for Fall 2014, and General Availability is slated for 2015 (Safe Harbor applying to both).

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2sIAAQ